# PowerShell "foreach-object -Parallel" get variable value out of the loop

Tags: powershell, parallel.foreach, foreach-object

how to get variable value set in a "Foreach-Object -Parallel" loop outside of the "Foreach-Object" function/loop? In my example, the variable `limitReached` has no value at `write-host` in the end. I need to use `While` loop in the script, below is a simplified version of what I am doing.

```
$retries = 2
$secondsDelay = 2
$a = "house"



1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

    $retryCount = 0
    $ready = $false

    while ($ready -ne $true)
    {      
        if ($a -eq "hello")
        {
            Write-Output ("a is equal ""hello"".")
            $ready = $true                    
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output ("a is not equal ""hello"".")

            if ($retryCount -ge $using:retries)
            {
                Write-Output ("a is STILL not equal ""hello"".")
                $global:limitReached = $true
                Write-Host "Checking - limitReached value is [$limitReached]"
                return
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Output ("let's give more runs.")`n
                Start-Sleep $using:secondsDelay
                $retryCount++
            }                    
        }
    }        
}

Write-Host "I need this value - limitReached here is [$global:limitReached]"
```

The result I expect:

`I need this value - limitReached here is [TRUE]`

The result I get:

[image]

Comment: As both items (`1` and `2`) run **parallel** (and the `2`nd thread might be finished first), which `$limitReached` would you expect to be returned? Anyways, you might use a `[hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})`  to return values from the threads.

Comment: @iRon it would be fine if any fails, it does not matter to me if first or second, as long as any sets `global:limitReached` to TRUE it is fine. And I need to get it at the end of the script, this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of defining a global variable is not correct.
You should instead write declare it just below `$a = "house"` as `$limitReached = $false`

remove the `$global:` from your code and keep only the variable names, and you should be good to go.

Here is the updated code that gives the output `I need this value - limitReached here is [True]` as well as the loop outputs.

```
$retries = 2
$secondsDelay = 2
$a = "house"
$limitReached = $false

1..2 | ForEach-Object {
    $retryCount = 0
    $ready = $false

    while ($ready -ne $true)
    {      
        if ($a -eq "hello")
        {
            Write-Output ("a is equal ""hello"".")
            $ready = $true                    
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output ("a is not equal ""hello"".")

            if ($retryCount -ge $retries)
            {
                Write-Output ("a is STILL not equal ""hello"".")
                $limitReached = $true
                Write-Host "Checking - limitReached value is [$limitReached]"
                return
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Output ("let's give more runs.")`n
                Start-Sleep $secondsDelay
                $retryCount++
            }                    
        }
    }        
}

Write-Host "I need this value - limitReached here is [$limitReached]"
```

[image]

Comment: @Kreetchy awesome. I did try without `$global:`, but then PoSh used to highlight it saying "variable is assigned but never used", so global did solve that issues, but still result did not bring. Your suggestion worked, thanks!

Comment: Yes because just like most other coding languages(if you ever studied or practiced any), you need to first declare the variable BEFORE assigning it. Here we do it by declaring it at the top, so we can still retrieve the value even outside of the loop, as per your use-case.

Comment: sorry, I see you have amended my script by removing `-Parallel`, this is the main point where it fails. So this is why `$global` is needed and so on. So the case is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

(In case you do want to run the processes in `-Parallel`)
As both items (`1` and `2`) run parallel (and the `2`nd thread might be finished first), which `$limitReached` would you expect to be returned?
Anyways, you might use the `[hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})` class but probably easiest is simply using the PowerShell to retrieve the results:

```
$Result = 1..2 |ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    for ($i = 1; $i -le 4 - $_; $i++) {
        Write-Host "Time: $(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss'), Id: $_, Count: $i"
        Sleep -Seconds $i
    }
    @{
        ID = $_
        Count = $i
        limitReached = $_ -eq 1
    }
}
```

```
Time: 14:57:17, Id: 1, Count: 1
Time: 14:57:17, Id: 2, Count: 1
Time: 14:57:18, Id: 2, Count: 2
Time: 14:57:18, Id: 1, Count: 2
Time: 14:57:20, Id: 1, Count: 3
```

```
$Result |ConvertTo-Json
```

```
[
  {
    "Count": 3,
    "ID": 2,
    "limitReached": false
  },
  {
    "Count": 4,
    "ID": 1,
    "limitReached": true
  }
]
```

Comment: don't you see any other way, without wrapping whole run into a variable ($result)? As here is the problem - we do not see the progress/logs once whole run is assigned to variable.
It is very weird, that there is no way to pass variable's value out of "foreach-object" in parallel way.

Comment: That comes with the concept of parallel threads: they all (including your main thread) run concurrently. You can still write simultaneously to the console (using e.g. `Write-Host`, as shown in the updated answer), but if you want communicate between the threads, you will need to use a synchronized object or use events. or wait till all the processes are finalized which the PowerShell pipeline conveniently does for you if you assign it to a variable.